# Cors error when invoked authorize url from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I am using keycloak adapter js file for active directory users. For active directory users keycloak adapter identifies and it cannot identify non-active-directory users, hence, I am trying to invoke the authorize link manually.  Is there a way to execute the following link https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX-YYY-ZZZ-111-X1Z1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=test&scope=openid&sso_reload=true using pure javascript code as it gives me CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX-YYY-ZZZ-111-X1Z1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=test&scope=openid&sso_reload=true' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The javascript code is as follows :

```
  var HttpClient = function() {
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
get: function () { return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0)'; } 
 });
 this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
    var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
            aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
    }

    anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
    anHttpRequest.send(  );
}
```

}

```
var authorizeUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX-YYY-ZZZ-111-X1Z1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=test&scope=openid&sso_reload=true" 

var client = new HttpClient();
 client.get(authorizeUrl, function(response) {
    // do something with response
    alert(response)
 });
```

Comment: You need to route the request through your server (also please google error messages first; this is an extremely common probem which has been asked and answered many times)

Comment: @ChrisG I get the microsoft login screen when I type the URL from browser, any solution why XMLHttpRequest is not working for this url???

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is right there in the error message: the server doesn't allow CORS, which means you cannot request the URL from a different origin, i.e. domain. A server has to specifically allow this by adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response (which is the case for APIs intended to be used by client-side JavaScript). A quick and dirty fix is to use a CORS proxy, a stable solution is to make the request on your own backend and forward the result to your client-side code.